# how to compile a server application to a certain destination ( has only Makefile )

Tags: compilation, makefile

***To no avail I try to compile code to a certain distination. 
How to compile a server application to a certain destination ( has only Makefile ) ?***

Tried:

```
make DESTDIR=/opt/mydeamon
```

But this fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make itself has no standard way of doing installations. If the installation is done using a Makefile it is up to the Makefile author to write rules for how make should do it.

But a common way it to provide a `make install` target and i think a common variable for specifying installation path is `PREFIX`.

Your should probably read some README or INSTALL file or even check the Makefile file for instructions if this is a source package that you have downloaded somewhere.